Generation agent in storage without the use of the store block
How I can do to generate a new agent directly in the storage?
when new agent is generate by source, it moves trhough the path to arrive at storage, but i want that the new agent is generated in the storage. I need to make the operation to retrieve and store again after and i want skip the first store moving.
